# Error while passing query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Whenever I pass a query after a PDO connection the page returns an 500 error. I don't know whats causing the issue. I am using LAMP server. Here is the code:

```
$user = 'root';
$database = 'mysql';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = 'pdotest';
$host = 'localhost';

$dsn = $database . ":" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname;

$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt) or die('Can\'t establish connection');

// This is where it gives 500 error

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM pdo");
```

Comment: Print the error: try { $pdo->query('select * from pdo'); } catch (PDOException $e) { die($e->getMessage()); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I made a silly mistake. Just missed a host in dsn. Changing dsn from:

```
$dsn = $database . ":" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname;
```

To:

```
$dsn = $database . ":host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname;
```

solved my problem.